# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: javafx

my program will run 15 to 20 min correctly after some it shows following **error  :**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
        at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3595)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3625)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3486)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:559)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1719)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Looks like a threading issue. Never access/modify the GUI from a background thread.

Comment: And what do you expect to get from us? What is your question?